# How to increase throughput making use of coroutine / completeableFuture<> spring boot appication

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, concurrency, coroutine, completable-future

So, I have a External Api call and 2 heavy database query in my service layer, the blocking code looks like this

```
    override fun getTotalIncomeByMonth(retailerMsisdn: String, month: Int, year: Int): SummaryDto {


        val incomes1: TransactionSummaryDao? =
            service1.func(
                retailerMsisdn, month, year
            ) // a heavy query runs under the hood

        val income2: Double = service2.func(
            retailerMsisdn, month, year
        ) // another heavy query runs under the hood


        val totalSimSale: Double = externalApiService.apiCall(
            retailerMsisdn, month, year
        )  // okHttp api call 

        return SummaryDto().apply {
            this.incomeX = income1
            this.incomeY = income2
            this.simSale = simsale
        }
    }
```

i was thinking of creating a threadpool bean the and use the executor make calls concurrently, but this threadpool is going to be limited though out the application, i thought of using 2 threads per request to handle this scenerio,

```
    override fun getTotalIncomeByMonth(retailerMsisdn: String, month: Int, year: Int): SummaryDto {

        val executor = ThreadPoolTaskExecutor()
        executor.corePoolSize = 2
        executor.maxPoolSize = 2
        executor.setQueueCapacity(3)
        executor.setTaskDecorator(MdcTaskDecorator())
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix(Constant.NAME_ASYNC_THREAD_PREFIX)
        executor.setWaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown(true)
        executor.initialize()

        val incomes1: CompleteableFutur<Dao> =CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
          {
            service1.func(
                retailerMsisdn, month, year
            ) // a heavy query runs under the hood (IO)
          }, executor )

        val income2: CompleteableFutur<Double>  = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(
          {
            service2.func(
               retailerMsisdn, month, year
            ) // another heavy query runs under the hood ( IO)
          }, executor) 

        val totalSale =  
externalApiService.apiCall(
            retailerMsisdn, month, year
        )  // okHttp api call  (IO)

        return SummaryDto().apply {
            this.incomeX = income1.join()
            this.incomeY = income2.join()
            this.simSale = simsale.join()
        }
    }
```

is it a good approach of doing it, or should I consider using kotlin coroutine and suspending functions? can the caller thread handle the whole 3 IO operations without using additional dispatcher threads? I know additional thread creation is costly, so want to keep in mind that as well. user of the application is almost 1 million , can have 1000 request/second

thought of using kotlin coroutine using the caller thread only

```
override fun getTotalIncomeByMonth(retailerMsisdn: String, month: Int, year: Int): SummaryDto {
    return runBlocking {
        val income1: Dao? = async {
            service1.func(retailerMsisdn, month, year)
            // a heavy query runs under the hood
        }

        val income2: Double = async {
            service2.func(retailerMsisdn, month, year)
            // another heavy query runs under the hood
        }

        val simSale: Double = async {
            externalApiService.apiCall(retailerMsisdn, month, year)
            // OkHttp API call
        }

        SummaryDto().apply {
            this.incomeX = income1.await()
            this.incomeY = income2.await()
            this.simSale = simSale.await()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: One question, why do you use `async` for the API call in the coroutines example, but not in the executor-based example?

Comment: The first thing you should do is *measure* and make sure the problem is in your code. It might be that the database or external API are the limiting factors. If it is, changing your code won't help (much).

Answer (score 0):

First, be careful to avoid creating a thread pool every time when using the executor approach, this might be costly.

With that aside, using coroutines can work just as well given the same number of threads, with the benefit of being more convenient to write.
However, you're not using the same number of threads here in your coroutine version. As you said, you're only using the caller thread, which means at most one coroutine can be executed at a time (there is no parallelism, only concurrency). This, in turn, means that one heavy IO will block the only thread and will prevent others from being run, and thus will perform slower than your first approach (but with less memory).

Instead of just using the calling thread, you could make use of the predefined `Dispatchers.IO`, and you'll still be able to limit the number of threads used by each request using `Dispatchers.IO.limitedParallelism(2)` (if you consider this desirable):

```kotlin
override fun getTotalIncomeByMonth(retailerMsisdn: String, month: Int, year: Int): SummaryDto {
    return runBlocking {
        val income1: Dao? = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            service1.func(retailerMsisdn, month, year)
            // a heavy query runs under the hood
        }

        val income2: Double = async(Dispatchers.IO) {
            service2.func(retailerMsisdn, month, year)
            // another heavy query runs under the hood
        }

        val simSale: Double = async {
            externalApiService.apiCall(retailerMsisdn, month, year)
            // OkHttp API call
        }

        SummaryDto().apply {
            this.incomeX = income1.await()
            this.incomeY = income2.await()
            this.simSale = simSale.await()
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you can choose to still use the caller thread by not specifying a dispatcher. In the code above, I'm running the 3rd call (the API call) under the caller thread, like in your executor example, while the 2 others are run on the IO dispatcher. I haven't used `limitedParallelism(2)` because it would be redundant if we just launch 2 coroutines.

All that being said, I would refrain from using `runBlocking` here. You should instead use `coroutineScope` and make your function `suspend` itself, and bubble this up to your Spring controller (they do support `suspend` functions if you use webflux).